# Rails error : active_support/core_ext/string (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, spree

I installed Spree commerce for a website I'm making and needed to upgrade my Ruby version to 2.3.0 I've installed rvm and made the 2.3.0 the default ruby version to use.

I've re-installed Rails and Bundler but when I try to make to add the spree gem to my file using this formula:

```
    spree install --auto-accept
```

then I get this error :

```
/Users/steph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/string (LoadError)
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_cmd-3.0.8/lib/spree_cmd/installer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_cmd-3.0.8/lib/spree_cmd.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_cmd-3.0.8/bin/spree:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/spree:22:in `load'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/spree:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/steph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm really not sure what to do, i've tried re-installing bundler and rails et spree but nothing different.

I've been following these instructions : https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html

Can anyone help me with this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you run a `gem list` command, can you see `active_support` with the same version as `rails` in the output?

Comment: No, I only have

`*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
bundler (1.11.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
json (default: 1.8.3)
minitest (5.8.3)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (default: 2.0.17)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (default: 4.2.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
spree_cmd (3.0.8)
test-unit (3.1.5)
thor (0.19.1)`

Comment: I've runned the command `gem install activesupport` and it worked, thanks alot ! :)

Comment: try mentioning the spree version in gemfile like '3.0.4' and here is an amazing tutorial for [spree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pirTIAy1NVM)  this one helped me a lot.